# Is there a way to schedule a SikuliX script to run automatically?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, command-prompt, sikuli

I've managed to run the script from the command line thinking that i could possibly use windows Schedule Task to run it, but it doesn't run command prompt or anything. When i go and check the task it says it completed. Im running windows8. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .bat file to execute your sikuli sript. .bat files can be scheduled with Windows 8, but you may need to schedule that task as SYSTEM or as the admin.